# Recombination rate/time calculation for plasma vs. solid state semiconductors

Tags: plasma-physics

I've been able to find how to calculate the recombination rate for semiconductors as a function of the type of semiconductor (like silicon), the doping material, the concentration of the excess carrier and resistivity, and the model for recombination.  However, I don't know about the recombination rate calculation for a gaseous plasma.  Can a similar relationship be used to calculate the recombination rate of plasma, where the electrons would be more excited?  I suppose that would have to assume that the plasma would be a semiconductor, while generally atmospheric gases are considered insulators, but otherwise I was wondering what calculation you apply for plasma of say, neon or nitrogen (not sure if it differs for thermally or electrically dominated plasma).

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of recombination processes in plasma, three-body (collisional) and radiative (or photo-recombination). The distinction is based on what particle removes excessive momentum and energy when an ion and an electron recombine. In the three-body recombination it is another electron, in the radiative recombination it is a photon. A good starting point for this subject is the [NRL Plasma Formulary](http://www.nrl.navy.mil/ppd/content/nrl-plasma-formulary), it contains main formulas and references. This is extracted from the Formulary:
[image]
[image]

Comment: There is also third type of recombination process in plasma called "Dielectronic recombination".